# <NavHashLink> 'react-router-hash-link' How to Simulate Scrollspy with Component

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-navigation, scrollspy

I have a version of a webpage that uses the following style of scrollspy:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#item-1-1

> "When successfully implemented, your nav or list group will update
> accordingly, moving the .active class from one item to the next based
> on their associated targets."

When the element with certain ID is on the screen it activates the Navlink and highlights it. I have translated it to a React App and have imported  from 'react-router-hash-link'. Since I have done that, the scrollspy which highlights the nav link when the id (#) is on the screen no longer works. Is there a solution to using  to simulate this scrollspy functionality with this component?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`react-ui-scrollspy`](https://github.com/pettiboy/react-ui-scrollspy#react-ui-scrollspy) it is very easy to use.

When the element with certain ID is on the screen it will highlight the `navitem` containing corresponding `data-to-scrollspy-id`.

It will also append your `URL` with `#<id>`.

*Full disclosure: I maintain this package.*

1. In your navigation component

```
<div>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="first">Section 1</p>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="second">Section 2</p>
</div>
```

2. Wrap the elements you want to spy on in the `<ScrollSpy>` component.

```
import ScrollSpy from "react-ui-scrollspy";

<ScrollSpy>
  <div id="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
</ScrollSpy>
```

3. Write styles for when the navigation element which is active in your `index.css`

```css
.active-scroll-spy {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```